# How to implement OAuth for community user self-registration with email verification

Tags: oauth2, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, connected-apps, customer-community, ios

**My Requirement:** I am creating a iOS native application that is using Salesforce Mobile SDK 3.3.1 I am using OAuth2 for authantication. This application should allow community user to Login and Self-Register. Self registration should not allow user to directly login to mobile app, verification mail will be sent to user and after creating the password from that emailed link he should be able to login in mobile application.

**What I have done:** I have made a connected app on my SF org and I am able to authenticate community user from mobile application using OAuth2.  , I am also able to do self-registration for community user. After self registration user is directly loggedIn in mobile application. Up to this point everything is working perfectly.

**My Question :** As I explained above that according to my requirement, community user should not be directly logged-In after self-registration. He should check his email and comeback to app and should only be able to enter in mobile app after login. So I updated self-refistration controller in my SF Org so after self-registration user is displayed a message that please check your email. But my problem is that after displaying message on webview of OAuth and control is not coming back to application in any of the callback methods like "postLaunchAction","launchErrorAction","postLogoutAction" or "switchUserAction" It should comeback to app like after login using redirect url.

**What I tried:** I tried to load login page after displaying the message But this does not help login page is opened but after login application don't get control and web portal of community app is opened in webview of OAuth.

Please guide Me how to do this.

Vishnu Sharma